# folder permissions changeing and i don't know why

Tags: script, permissions

I have a Python script that moves files from a folder on my pi to a mounted network drive folder, linked to a Box account.

The script seems to intermittently stop moving the files, and on further inspection, I've noticed the directory permissions being changed from 0777 to 0755, so no wonder only user PI can write files if it's 0755.

1) The script is being called buy user `motion`, so does it have `motion`s permissions when moving files between directories?

2) Can this directory's permissions change by them self, if so how?

3) would adding `sudo` to the front of the `mv` command in the script patch this problem?

4) is it a more elegant solution to make user `motion` the owner of the script and directories?

5) Could accessing this directory from another computer, via the box site, in any way change its permissions?

Your help and advise it always welcome,

Regards,

Reggie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes.

2) No. Probably what happens is the connection times out, and it gets remounted with the wrong permission.

3) Yes. Not very elegantly, though, as you point out yourself.

4) Yes, that would be one way to solve it. Who is the current owner?

5) Probably not.

Have a look in your `/etc/fstab` - there should be an entry for this mount point, and from there you can set the default permissions.

Comment: 4) the owner of the source & destination directories are both root. I had a look in the fstab file, but don't know how to set the default permissions so user motion can access it. I currently have --- https://dav.box.com/dav /home/pi/box  davfs  rw,noexec,noauto,user,async,_netdev,uid=pi,gid=pi  0 ---

Comment: Would this work in the fstab file:--- dav.box.com/dav /home/pi/box davfs rwx,noexec,noauto,user,async,_netdev,uid=motion,gid=motion 0 --- i've chainged the rw to rwx, the uid=pi to uid=motion and the gid-pi to gid=motion?

Comment: This seems reasonable to me, but the most important question is - does it work?

Comment: dav.box.com/dav /home/pi/box davfs rw,noexec,noauto,user,async,_netdev,uid=motion,gid=motion 0 works

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bex for your help :)

I think it's working now by changing the uid and gid to motion in the fstab davfs mount command. I used [this page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.davfs) for reference.

I also noticed that the mounted directory had 0777 permissions with user **pi**, then I modified the fstab file then did a reboot; to test the re mount.

Following the reboot the permissions changed to 0755 with user **motion** ; this may explain how the permissions could change, as you suspected.

I'm happy, thanks again,

Reggie :)

P.S. I didn't change the **rw** to **rwx** after looking at the above link, i didn't think it was valid.